# mediafilesegmenter only creating aac files

Tags: http, streaming, live

I am trying to create files for http live streaming. I am using Apple's mediafilesegmenter. I downloaded a sample movie (sample_iTunes.mov from http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1425), an MPEG-4 file. It plays fine in QuickTime.

When I run this:

```
mediafilesegmenter sample_iTunes.mov
```

I get the prog_index.m3u8 index file and a bunch of .aac files instead of .ts files. I read the man mediafilesegmenter 3 times but have not figured out why I'm getting audio files rather than video/audio files.

thanks for your help

Nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the problem. I opened the file in QuickTime player and then chose File > Save For Web. I selected iPhone and it created a .m4v file. I ran mediafilesegmenter on this file and it then created the .ts files. Those streamed properly.